# Can `chrome.*` extension API's be used inside content scripts?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use `chrome.windows.onCreated` but I got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCreated' of undefined`. I noticed in the samples, all calls to `chrome.*` API's seem to originate from background scripts? Can I not use them in content scripts?

I want to trigger clicks in my browser. Then get some information (scrape) in popup window. For that I think I will need to know when a window is opened. So I need `windows.onCreated`? Can I use that in content scripts? Or how will I combine background and content scripts?

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation for [Content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html):

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They **cannot**:
>
> - Use `chrome.*` APIs (except for parts of [`chrome.extension`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html))
> - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

These limitations can **indirectly** be avoided, mainly by [sending messages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) within the extension. The documentation offers several [examples](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html) which involves message passing. Prior Chrome 20, the message API methods was called `onRequest` and `sendRequest`. Since version 20, they're called `onMessage` and `sendMessage`.

Here's an answer which mentions the steps how to pass a message from a content script to a popup: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617742