# Chrome Extension: Change Address bar Button Background color at runtime

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to change button background color on page load event but so far I did not find any such method at all. If it is not possible then I am happy to use some pre-defined images that loads up after page load.

I have tried the following, without success:

script.js

```
// chrome.browserAction.setIcon("red.png");
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:'red.png'});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Domain Colors",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["script.js"]
  }],
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*" ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Colry",
    "default_icon": "blue.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the code. http://pastie.org/5438480  I was talking about address bar button

Comment: for some weird reason I am getting *setBadgeBackgroundColor* or *setIcon* method undefined.

Comment: See [Can `chrome.*` extension API's be used inside content scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700822/can-chrome-extension-apis-be-used-inside-content-scripts/11700893#11700893)

Comment: Aah. So what you recommend? Message passing?

Comment: I am getting a bit confuse. Should I send a message to sendIcon() method or sendBadgeText by passing paramer as a JSON Object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use the [`browserAction`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) API, a [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) is required. If you want to keep your current control flow (update icon via a content script), you need to [pass messages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html). Here's the bare minimum:

```
// script.js
chrome.extension.sendMessage('');
// background.js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
        color: 'red',
        tabId: sender.tab.id
    });
});
```

The manifest file needs one additional entry:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

You don't need content scripts for the purpose of detecting page loads. A single event listener can be used (in the background page):

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'loading') {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
            color: 'red',
            tabId: tabId
        });
    }
});
```

Have a close look at the documentation of [`chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeBackgroundColor). There are also [lots of examples using the browserAction API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#samples), you should be able to get a working extension yourself by looking at these samples.

Comment: Thansk for your snippet. Sorry for being so dumb but.. I am trying it but somehow it's not refreshing background.html file even if **reload** the extension. It's keep showing old code and keep executing it. How to force so that background.js reflects the changes?

Comment: Ok turned out that .js page was being cached. BackgroundBadgeText did not work for me however setIcon() did work but that is making changes across all tabs rather selective one.

Comment: @Volatil3 I had one small typo in my answer. Does it work now?

Comment: **tabId: sender.tab.id** Is not making any difference.

Comment: I also noted one thing that the event **onMessage** does not fire randomly when I refresh a page. Is it a normal behavior?

Comment: ok I sorted out showing in selective tab but randomness of not firing events is still mystery for me.

Comment: @Volatil3 Probably because you're visiting https websites, which are excluded by the match pattern. For this reason, I recommend to use the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` method, which works for all tabs.

Comment: I had a bit of a struggle with this one. Turns out you have to have at least `"browser_action": {}` in your _manifest.json_. If it's not there, you'll get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined` error. Perhaps it's worth mentioning in the answer?