# (TypeError): Cannot call method 'setBadgeText' of undefined

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-chrome-extension

I am implementing  chrome extension  using GWT.I have created the mapping in manifest.json & written the external java script file.In the background.js script,i have written  function,in that set badge text i.e  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText(count);.I am passing the string value from gwt class using gwt+jsni method.The method in gwt code  is

```
     public static native void passValue(String updateCount) /*-{
        $wnd.realTimeUpdateCount(updateCount);
    }-*/;    
The Methods in the java script :  
        function realTimeUpdateCount(count) {

      localStorage.unreadCount =  count;
      updateCount();
        }

       function updateCount() {
         if (!localStorage.hasOwnProperty('unreadCount')) {
          chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"images/favIcon.ico"});
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:"0"});
      } else {
           chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText(localStorage.unreadCount);
      }
       }
```

Here is my manifest.json file:-

```
{
  "name": "A browser action with no icon that makes the page red",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "permissions": [
     "tabs",
    "webNavigation", 
    "http://127.0.0.1:8888/Engile.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "4D1B5509A17D34BAE8DB33C353725838.cache.html"
  ],  
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Make this page red",
    "default_icon": "images/favIcon.ico"

  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Here is my background.js:-

```
function realTimeUpdateCount(count) {


    localStorage.unreadCount =  count;
    updateIcon();

}

if (chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.onStartup) {
      chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
        console.log('Starting browser... updating icon.');
        updateIcon();
      });
    } else {

      chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
        console.log('Window created... updating icon.');
        updateIcon();
      });
    }
function updateIcon() {



    if (!localStorage.hasOwnProperty('unreadCount')) {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"images/favIcon.ico"});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:"?"});
      } else {

        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
          text: localStorage.unreadCount
        });
      }

    }



function goToApp() {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[0, 200, 0, 100]});
      console.log('Going to app...');
      chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(undefined, function(tabs) {

        console.log('Opening the application ...');
        chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://server.ensarm.com:8082/EngileLive/Engile.html'});
      });
    }
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(goToApp);
```

When the browser is load the default 0 value is showing properly on Icon.The  real time value is coming properly in updateCount() method. But  control come on this chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText(count); line,it throws following exception :

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot call method 'setBadgeText' of undefined
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

can anybody please help help on this?What is issue in code.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using chrome manifest version 3, its [**`chrome.action`**](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/) (not `chrome.browserAction`) that must be used.
Example :

```
chrome.action.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: '#00FF00' })
chrome.action.setBadgeText({
    tabId: activeTab.id,
    text: 'text'
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can only call the chrome.browserAction calls from your background script file (I was having the same problem)

See:

[Chrome Extension: Change Address bar Button Background color at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564277/chrome-extension-change-address-bar-button-background-color-at-runtime)

Comment: i'm calling the chrome.browserAction only on the background.html and i got the error the same way...

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
else {
           chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:localStorage.unreadCount});
      }
```

instead of

```
else {
           chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText(localStorage.unreadCount);
      }
```

`browserAction.setBadgeText` takes json object as an input.

## References

- [chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeText)

Comment: Thank you,Sudarshan....I have already used both statement but still same exception is coming.Any other solution for  this?

Comment: Hi Sudarshan,above I have added two files manifest.json & background.js.In second file that is background.js function _realTimeUpdateCount(count)_ is called from GWT code (code which is mentioned in above question) using json.The string value is passed to this function.Please guide on this.

Comment: @dhananjay: It will be great if you post all your code by editing your question, it will be helpful for others also.

Comment: @dhananjay: I tried with your code, it is working correctly for me, is this the code you are using?

Comment: @dhananjay: Where is this code `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText(count); ` it is not in `background.js` , where is it?

Comment: Hi Sudarshan,in above background.js code,the count is assign to localStorage.unreadCount & localStorage.unreadCount given to chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23310/discussion-between-dhananjay-and-sudarshan)