# Invoke or use Chrome Object from javascript

Tags: google-chrome, object, google-chrome-devtools, device

I'm trying to customize my own `chrome://inspect/#devices` , I see it uses `utils.js` and `inspect.js` and at the same time it uses a global "chrome" object in the original ones, how do I invoke it from my own `inspect.js`? Right know I just have a local clone:

Clone folder of chrome://inspect/#devices

- `devices.html`
- `inspect.js`
- `util.js`
- `jquery.js`

So I load devices.html but is not working, and the first obstacle I have is that global object "chrome" is not available for `inspect.js`.

I found a somehow related thread [Can `chrome.*` extension API's be used inside content scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700822/can-chrome-extension-apis-be-used-inside-content-scripts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome://inspect` is one of the build-in Chrome pages (all are listed here - chrome://about/). These pages are considered an integral part of the browser and they have access to special actions (via `chrome` object). Browser will not inject `chrome` object into the regular pages (such as your copy of the `inspect` page).

Unfortunately, you won't be able to modify `chrome://inspect` page (even with an extension as you can't inject scripts into `chrome://` pages). However, you might be able to recreate that page in an extension using [debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger#method-getTargets).