# Pass data from Background.js to Popup.js to silently update Popup.html's DOM while Popup.html is not clicked or opened

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make my Popup.js be able to get any messages sent from Background.js at anytime, and then modify DOM in Popup.html while Popup.html is **NOT** clicked or opened.

I have tried two of the following methods:

1)

```
 var x = chrome.extension.getViews({type:"popup"});

 console.log(x[0]);  // undefined
```

2)

Implement `chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) { })` in the    Background.js, and `chrome.extension.connect({name: "abc"})` in Popup.js

This method works, however only when Popup.html is clicked or opened.

Now im trying the message passing method which doesn't work either:

**Popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  switch(request.type){
    case "get_id":
       $( "#showBtn" ).attr('data-resource', request.id);   //DOM update data-resource failed
       chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log("hello background.js");  //no log recorded
    break;
  }
});
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  switch(request.type){
    case "get":
        var url= request.resource;    //message from content script
            $.get( url , function(data){         
              chrome.runtime.sendMessage({  //send to Popup.js
                            type: "get_id", 
                            id: data.id
              });
            });                  
    break;
  }
});
```

I could implement `runtime.sendMessage`'s callback in my Popup.js to get data from `runtime.onMessage`'s response in Background.js or even use `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().backgroundData` in Popup.js to get `window.backgroundData` in Background.js, but they have no way to tell when to get the relevant data when they are available in Background.js...

**EDIT:**

I have finally found a way to do it...and in case somebody is interested:

**Manifest**

```
"background": {
    "page": "popup.html"
 },

"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
```

**Popup.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <button id="lol">yeppe skipdly duuuu</button>
      <button id="huh" data-resource=""></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Background.js**

```
$( "#lol" ).on( "click", function(){
  $("#huh").attr('data-resource', "hahaha");     //will make <button id="huh" data-resource="hahaha"></button>  !!
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                       type: "check"
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   switch(request.type){
       case "check":
         console.log("hello Background.js!");
       break;
   }
});
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103903/howto-send-a-message-from-content-script-to-inactive-popup-chrome-extension

Comment: thanks again Rob W. i will explore chrome.storage API now :D

Comment: @RobW I have got `chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {` in my Popup.js to detect changes of my storage in Background.js `chrome.storage.local.set({'value': "lala"}, function() {   // Notify that we saved  console.log('Settings saved');});`. Does it work like that cuz that is not working  :(

Comment: @twlart The idea is that you keep track of the state outside the popup. When the state is updated (`chrome.storage.local.set`), the popup should be notified (e.g. through `chrome.storage.local.onChanged`). When the popup opens for the first time, you have to read the state of the popup from this externally stored state (e.g. using `chrome.storage.local.get`).

Comment: thanks @RobW onChanged method in Popup.js doesn't seem to get triggered by changes in my Background.js unless the changes were in Popup.js as well..

Comment: @twlart Try "Option 2" of the answer.