# Not receiving response from background after sending message from popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send a message from popup to background and get message back from background.

I get the message from popup and it prints `Background received: Hi`, but it doesn't print `Popup received: Bye`.

*background.js*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("Background received: " + request.msg);
        sendResponse({msg: "Bye"});
    }
)
```

*popup.js*

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: "Hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log("Popup received: " + response.msg);
});
```

I've done this before, I'm sure, but I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong now. I must be overlooking something very simple. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think have a look at this post will definitely help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103903/howto-send-a-message-from-content-script-to-inactive-popup-chrome-extension

Comment: No need, everything works. I was just too tired and didn't look into popup's console. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Though, I could start using databases instead of sendMessage..

Comment: Yeah, there are several options rather than just using sendMessage: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/iFxhbJb_56c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must be too tired.. I was staring hopelessly in the **background** page's console and didn't even think to look into **popup** console. Everything worked as expected from start. Oh dear..